# WAS Non-HTTP activation - hooking application startup

Tags: wcf, was, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to integrate a netTcpBinding based application that is hosted inside WAS with an IoC container (autofac/spring).  Unfortunately, when it starts inside WAS and due to the fact that it is not an Http based application, no events are fired inside the Global application class.

I need to catch the application domain startup so that I can configure the IoC container.  Is there any way to do this when hosting in WAS?

I've seen horrible things involving using static classes inside App_Code folders, but I'd like something somewhat more testable and not quite as dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IInstanceProvider (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) and tell the WCF runtime to use it via a service behavior.

The service behavior can be configured with a custom host, configuration or with an attribute. Here an example of the latter:

```
public class DependencyInjectionServiceBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (var cdb in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var cd = cdb as ChannelDispatcher;
            if (cd != null)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
                {
                    ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new MyServiceFactory(serviceDescription.ServiceType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,  
            Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {}
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {}
}
```